# Is there a single logic symbol for "implies the negation of"?

Tags: logic

Is there a single logic symbol for "implies the negation of"?

(I came up with this question when studying English grammar, on realising that such a symbol when reversed and itself negated could be used to relate A and B in a sentence comprising a main clause followed by a concession clause, e.g. *A, even though B*, meaning *B does not imply the negation of A*.)

Comment: $\text{A}\rightarrow\neg\text{B}$?

Comment: @GPerez - That's two symbols: $\rightarrow$ and $\lnot$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In classical logic, this is equivalent to [NAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate).

*Proof.* The following are equivalent:

1. $A \rightarrow (\neg B)$
2. $(\neg A) \vee (\neg B)$
3. $\neg(A \wedge B)$

So you could denote it with a [Sheffer stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke). As in:

$$A \uparrow B = A \rightarrow \neg B$$

Comment: Thanks for this. Would turning it upside down be comprehensible to many people as an expression of the inverse relation?

Comment: @h34, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Definition).

Comment: Thanks @goblin. This is a full answer to the question, so I've accepted it and +1'ed it. But the symbolism is more pure-logical and less intuitive than I'd hoped. I'd thought there might be something that people could read in a grammatical and rhetorical context and link with destruction (*A stops B from being true*; cf. $\Rightarrow$ giving a feeling of flow), just going by the look of the symbol, and that was not only strikeable through but also nicely reversible. I think in my context I will go with $\rhd$, $\lhd$, $\ntriangleright$, $\ntriangleleft$.

Comment: @h34, I hear you. Tbh I find the equivalence between $A \rightarrow \neg B$ and $\neg(A \wedge B)$ to be a little difficult to understand intuitively. Part of the problem is that we often like to view $\rightarrow$ as "causation" which strictly speaking it is not.

Comment: And thus in reverse Polish notation, D == NC